How to render side-by-side stereo video?
I want to render a 3d/stereoscopic video in an Apple Vision Pro window using RealityKit/RealityView. The video is a left-right stereo. The straight forward approach would be to spawn a quad, and give it a custom Shader Graph material, which has a CameraIndexSwitch, which chooses between the right texture vs the left texture.
Here's a screenshot showing the shader graph, and how it mixes between the right vs left texture based on eye index
The issue I have here is that I have to extract the video frames from my AVSampleBufferVideoRenderer. This should work ok, but not if I'm playing FairPlay content.
So, my question is, how to render stereo FairPlay videos in a SwiftUI RealityView?

CameraIndexSwitch is indeed the ticket here. ChatGPT seems to give a good answer for prompt "How can extract frames from AVSampleBufferVideoRenderer in Swift?"

Since you have all the visionOS components this is more of a swift/fairplay question
